# Mockito 5.8.0 ambiquity with varargs

Tags: java, mockito, variadic-functions

if one has a method such as

```
Long foo(String... s)
```

that you wish to mock, you can do

```
Mockito.when(myMock.foo(ArgumentMatchers.any(String[].class))).thenReturn(Long.valueOf(1));
```

and if a call occurs such as

```
myMock.foo();
myMock.foo("hello");
myMock.foo("hello", "there");
```

it will work fine.

However if a call is made like

```
myMock.foo((String[]) null);
```

if fails, as the definition need be nullable(String[].class);

However, if you define it as nullable(String[].class); then

```
myMock.foo("Hello");
```

will fail to match as it thinks the type of the matcher is Object, as it calculates that based on the or(String[].class, isNull()) definition.

So it doesn't appear that all cases can be handled by the same syntax. Or am i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily adapt `InstanceOf` matcher to match null parameters.

Alternatively, you can use `or` matcher.

Please be aware that Mockito took the opposite direction: in 2.1.0 they changed `any()` not to accept null values.

```java
class NullableInstanceOf extends InstanceOf {
    public static <T> T anyOrNull(Class<T> clazz) {
        Mockito.argThat(new NullableInstanceOf(clazz));
        return null;
    }

    public NullableInstanceOf(Class<?> clazz) {
        super(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object actual) {
        return actual == null || super.matches(actual);
    }
}
```

Alternative matcher

```java
AdditionalMatchers.or(ArgumentMatchers.isNull(String[].class), ArgumentMatchers.isA(String[].class)))
```

Note that alternative matcher is almost equivalent to the one used by `nullable(String[].class)`, but uses `isNull(String[].class)` instead of `isNull()`

Matchcer used by `nullable(String[].class)`

```java
AdditionalMatchers.or(ArgumentMatchers.isNull(), ArgumentMatchers.isA(String[].class)))
```

Test:

```java
class Foo {
    Long foo(String... s) {
        return 5L;
    }
}


public class NullableInstanceOfTest {

    Foo myMock = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        Mockito.when(myMock.foo(NullableInstanceOf.anyOrNull(String[].class))).thenReturn(1L);
    }

    @Test
    void matchesNoArgs() {
        Assertions.assertThat(myMock.foo()).isEqualTo(1L);
    }

    @Test
    void matchesOneArgs() {
        Assertions.assertThat(myMock.foo("hello")).isEqualTo(1L);
    }

    @Test
    void matchesTwoArgs() {
        Assertions.assertThat(myMock.foo("hello", "there")).isEqualTo(1L);
    }

    @Test
    void matchesNull() {
        Assertions.assertThat(myMock.foo((String[]) null)).isEqualTo(1L);
    }

}
```

Comment: my point is

nullable(String[].class) should match

foo("hello");

but doesn't

Comment: The reason is that `nullable` uses `isNull()` not `isNull(Class<T>)`. However current behaviour is documented in javadoc - `any` is documented to work with varargs "Since Mockito 5.0.0 this method can match varargs if the array type is specified, for example any(String[].class)." while `nullable` is documented not to work worth varargs: "Argument that is either null or of the given type." IMHO this is more a feature request than a bug.

Comment: But to be frank, I cannot remember when I saw a null array passed to varargs method - and I would flag this as a potential bug on a review.

Comment: i certainly agree passing null is not good.